# Creating a stereo WAV file using C

Tags: c, file, audio, wav

I am looking at creating a `WAV file` in C and have seen an example [here](http://karplus4arduino.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/making-wav-files-from-c-programs/).

This looks good, but I'm interested in adding two buffers to make the audio stereo **(the possibility to have different sound in each ear)**. If I set the number of channels to two, the audio plays out of the left channel only (which apparently is right, as the left channel is the first channel). I have read I must interleave it with the right channel.

Unfortunately I haven't found much online to help create a stereo WAV.

```
write_little_endian((unsigned int)(data[i]),bytes_per_sample, wav_file);
```

I've tried to create a second buffer, with half the amplitude to see if I could interleave.

```
for (j=0; i<BUF_SIZE; i++) {
    phase +=freq_radians_per_sample;
    buffertwo[i] = (int)((amplitude/2) * sin(phase));;
    }

write_wav("test.wav", BUF_SIZE, buffer, buffertwo, S_RATE);
```

(changing the function to take two short integer buffers)

And just doing

```
    write_little_endian((unsigned int)(data[i]),bytes_per_sample, wav_file);
    write_little_endian((unsigned int)(datatwo[i]),bytes_per_sample, wav_file);
```

But that does not work. That should in theory be interleaved.

Comment: Are you doing this on an Arduino, or just your own laptop or desktop?

Comment: I'm doing this on my laptop for now, plan is to run it on a small Linux device.

Thanks

Comment: Did you assign the variable `num_channels = 2;`? You need that for when you write the header of the wav file so it knows that there are two channels per frame.

Comment: Yes I did, and I also reset phase=0; before calling the second iterator. MediaInfo confirms I am now producing a 2 channel audio file, and the file size matches the bitrate, so I know both streams are being copied in.

Comment: I know I don't need to halve amplitude to do stereo, this is more to see if the left and the right are producing different tones

I will try without write_little_endian and let you know.

Comment: Safayet, thank you for your code. It does work -- I've tried to adapt it but I'm not having much luck. Can you see why? FYI -- sample rate is always hard coded to 44.1; so I have tried to remove some of the variables.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit as it completely changed the code that was already answered.  If you have problems with that new code, post it as a new question.

Comment: I have reposted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23146798/creating-a-stereo-sin-wav-using-c and marked Safayet's question as the answer as it is closest to the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I decided to give it a shot for fun and here is an alternative way to write a .wav file. It generates a file called `sawtooth_test.wav`. When you play it back, you should hear two different frequencies from left and right. (Don't play it back too loud. Its annoying.)

```
/*Compiles with gcc -Wall -O2 -o wavwrite wavwrite.c*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

/*
The header of a wav file Based on:
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
*/
typedef struct wavfile_header_s
{
    char    ChunkID[4];     /*  4   */
    int32_t ChunkSize;      /*  4   */
    char    Format[4];      /*  4   */
    
    char    Subchunk1ID[4]; /*  4   */
    int32_t Subchunk1Size;  /*  4   */
    int16_t AudioFormat;    /*  2   */
    int16_t NumChannels;    /*  2   */
    int32_t SampleRate;     /*  4   */
    int32_t ByteRate;       /*  4   */
    int16_t BlockAlign;     /*  2   */
    int16_t BitsPerSample;  /*  2   */
    
    char    Subchunk2ID[4];
    int32_t Subchunk2Size;
} wavfile_header_t;

/*Standard values for CD-quality audio*/
#define SUBCHUNK1SIZE   (16)
#define AUDIO_FORMAT    (1) /*For PCM*/
#define NUM_CHANNELS    (2)
#define SAMPLE_RATE     (44100)

#define BITS_PER_SAMPLE (16)

#define BYTE_RATE       (SAMPLE_RATE * NUM_CHANNELS * BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8)
#define BLOCK_ALIGN     (NUM_CHANNELS * BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8)

/*Return 0 on success and -1 on failure*/
int write_PCM16_stereo_header(FILE *file_p,
                                int32_t SampleRate,
                                int32_t FrameCount)
{
    int ret;
    
    wavfile_header_t wav_header;
    int32_t subchunk2_size;
    int32_t chunk_size;
    
    size_t write_count;
    
    subchunk2_size  = FrameCount * NUM_CHANNELS * BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8;
    chunk_size      = 4 + (8 + SUBCHUNK1SIZE) + (8 + subchunk2_size);
    
    wav_header.ChunkID[0] = 'R';
    wav_header.ChunkID[1] = 'I';
    wav_header.ChunkID[2] = 'F';
    wav_header.ChunkID[3] = 'F';
    
    wav_header.ChunkSize = chunk_size;
    
    wav_header.Format[0] = 'W';
    wav_header.Format[1] = 'A';
    wav_header.Format[2] = 'V';
    wav_header.Format[3] = 'E';
    
    wav_header.Subchunk1ID[0] = 'f';
    wav_header.Subchunk1ID[1] = 'm';
    wav_header.Subchunk1ID[2] = 't';
    wav_header.Subchunk1ID[3] = ' ';
    
    wav_header.Subchunk1Size = SUBCHUNK1SIZE;
    wav_header.AudioFormat = AUDIO_FORMAT;
    wav_header.NumChannels = NUM_CHANNELS;
    wav_header.SampleRate = SampleRate;
    wav_header.ByteRate = BYTE_RATE;
    wav_header.BlockAlign = BLOCK_ALIGN;
    wav_header.BitsPerSample = BITS_PER_SAMPLE;
    
    wav_header.Subchunk2ID[0] = 'd';
    wav_header.Subchunk2ID[1] = 'a';
    wav_header.Subchunk2ID[2] = 't';
    wav_header.Subchunk2ID[3] = 'a';
    wav_header.Subchunk2Size = subchunk2_size;
    
    write_count = fwrite(   &wav_header, 
                            sizeof(wavfile_header_t), 1,
                            file_p);
                    
    ret = (1 != write_count)? -1 : 0;
    
    return ret;
}

/*Data structure to hold a single frame with two channels*/
typedef struct PCM16_stereo_s
{
    int16_t left;
    int16_t right;
} PCM16_stereo_t;

PCM16_stereo_t *allocate_PCM16_stereo_buffer(int32_t FrameCount)
{
    return (PCM16_stereo_t *)malloc(sizeof(PCM16_stereo_t) * FrameCount);
}


/*Return the number of audio frames sucessfully written*/
size_t  write_PCM16wav_data(FILE*           file_p,
                            int32_t         FrameCount,
                            PCM16_stereo_t  *buffer_p)
{
    size_t ret;
    
    ret = fwrite(   buffer_p, 
                    sizeof(PCM16_stereo_t), FrameCount,
                    file_p);
                    
    return ret;
}

/*Generate two saw-tooth signals at two frequencies and amplitudes*/
int generate_dual_sawtooth( double frequency1,
                            double amplitude1,
                            double frequency2,
                            double amplitude2,
                            int32_t SampleRate,
                            int32_t FrameCount,
                            PCM16_stereo_t  *buffer_p)
{
    int ret = 0;
    double SampleRate_d = (double)SampleRate;
    double SamplePeriod = 1.0 / SampleRate_d;
    
    double Period1, Period2;
    double phase1, phase2;
    double Slope1, Slope2;
    
    int32_t k;
    
    /*Check for the violation of the Nyquist limit*/
    if( (frequency1*2 >= SampleRate_d) || (frequency2*2 >= SampleRate_d) )
    {
        ret = -1;
        goto error0;
    }
    
    /*Compute the period*/
    Period1 = 1.0 / frequency1;
    Period2 = 1.0 / frequency2;
    
    /*Compute the slope*/
    Slope1  = amplitude1 / Period1;
    Slope2  = amplitude2 / Period2;
    
    for(k = 0, phase1 = 0.0, phase2 = 0.0; 
        k < FrameCount; 
        k++)
    {
        phase1 += SamplePeriod;
        phase1 = (phase1 > Period1)? (phase1 - Period1) : phase1;
        
        phase2 += SamplePeriod;
        phase2 = (phase2 > Period2)? (phase2 - Period2) : phase2;
        
        buffer_p[k].left    = (int16_t)(phase1 * Slope1);
        buffer_p[k].right   = (int16_t)(phase2 * Slope2);
    }
    
error0:
    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    FILE* file_p;

    double frequency1 = 493.9; /*B4*/
    double amplitude1 = 0.65 * (double)SHRT_MAX;
    double frequency2 = 392.0; /*G4*/
    double amplitude2 = 0.75 * (double)SHRT_MAX;
    
    double duration = 10; /*seconds*/
    int32_t FrameCount = duration * SAMPLE_RATE;
    
    PCM16_stereo_t  *buffer_p = NULL;
    
    size_t written;
    
    /*Open the wav file*/
    file_p = fopen("./sawtooth_test.wav", "wb");
    if(NULL == file_p)
    {
        perror("fopen failed in main");
        ret = -1;
        goto error0;
    }
    
    /*Allocate the data buffer*/
    buffer_p = allocate_PCM16_stereo_buffer(FrameCount);
    if(NULL == buffer_p)
    {
        perror("fopen failed in main");
        ret = -1;
        goto error1;        
    }

    /*Fill the buffer*/
    ret = generate_dual_sawtooth(   frequency1,
                                    amplitude1,
                                    frequency2,
                                    amplitude2,
                                    SAMPLE_RATE,
                                    FrameCount,
                                    buffer_p);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "generate_dual_sawtooth failed in main\n");
        ret = -1;
        goto error2;
    }
    
    /*Write the wav file header*/
    ret = write_PCM16_stereo_header(file_p,
                                    SAMPLE_RATE,
                                    FrameCount);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        perror("write_PCM16_stereo_header failed in main");
        ret = -1;
        goto error2;
    }
    
    /*Write the data out to file*/
    written = write_PCM16wav_data(  file_p,
                                    FrameCount,
                                    buffer_p);
    if(written < FrameCount)
    {
        perror("write_PCM16wav_data failed in main");
        ret = -1;
        goto error2;
    }

    /*Free and close everything*/    
error2:
    free(buffer_p);
error1:
    fclose(file_p);
error0:
    return ret;    
}
```

Comment: Hi,
this is a good piece of code to start with. But I found two issue when I generated the wave-file and heard it. It was noisy and I could not hear a major third (G4 to B4). When I inspected the binary file I found that 0x0A was replaced by 0x0D, 0x0A. So, the solution was to open the file with the option "wb" to open a binary file for writing.
Maybe you want to correct this. 
Another improvement was to subtract the DC offset which is amplitude/2.
Take care!
michaeL

Comment: Thank you, @MiCo and Evil. Good suggestion. Just accepted the edit.

Comment: No problem. I found your answer, trying to solve my own: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625243/batch-mixing-audio-given-timestamps-multiple-offsets-only-two-sounds-how-to but couldn't put togethet plst, slnt chunks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the function "write_little_endian". You shouldn't need to use it on your laptop.

Endianness is architecture specific. The original example was likely for an Arduino microcontroller board. Arduino boards use Atmel microcontrollers which are big-endian. Thats why the code you cited explicitly needs to convert the 16-bit integers to little-endian format.

Your laptop on the other hand, uses x86 processors which are already little endian so no conversion is necessary. If you want robust portable code to convert endianness, you can use the function `htole16` in Linux. Lookup the man pages to learn more about this function.

For a quick but non-portable fix, I would say just write out the entire 16bit value.

Also, I don't think you need to halve the amplitudes to go from mono to stereo.